# The option to change mouse cursor in gnome tweak tool has become permanently inactive. How to make it active and functioning again?

Tags: cursor-theme

I tried to change the codes in /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme and i found that may be i deleted it somehow. is it the reason behind it? if so how can i restore it and make the option in gnome tweak tool active again?

Comment: you deleted the content or entire file? and what is your 0S?

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I solved the problem.  I checked the packages for the directory /usr/share/icons, then i reinstalled the package 'x-cursor-themes' by running 'sudo apt install --reinstall xcursor-themes' and i got the file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the packages for the directory `/usr/share/icons`, then I reinstalled the package `x-cursor-themes` by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xcursor-themes
```

and I got the file back.